# Get all the social comments created in the specific publish page using SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

```
Get all the social comments created in the specific publish page using SharePoint 2010
```

Do we have any powershell script please advise ?

Comment: Get all the social comments and Ratings created in the specific publish page using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below PowerShell which fetch the comment for a specific user. You can iterate the below PowerShell after fetching all the users.

```
##Get all the social comments created by the specific user using SharePoint 2010 web service in powershell  
$uri="http://serverName:portNumber/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx?wsdl"  

## $userAccountName is a string that contains the specific account name  
$userAccountName="domainName\userName"  

## $maximumItemsToReturn is used to specify the maximum number of comments to return.   
## This value must be null, or nonnegative and less than 1001.   
## If null or 0, this method returns up to 1000 social comments  
$maximumItemsToReturn=0  

## $startIndex is used to specify the zero-based index of the total set of social comments at which the returned set of social comments starts  
$startIndex=0  

## Web Service Reference - http://Site/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx  
$socialDataServiceWebServiceReference = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential   
$SocialCommentDetail=$socialDataServiceWebServiceReference.GetCommentsOfUser($userAccountName,$maximumItemsToReturn,$startIndex)  

## $SocialCommentDetail is of Type: [SocialDataService Web service].SocialCommentDetail()  
##[SocialDataService Web service].SocialCommentDetail() - Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialcommentdetail_members.aspx  


foreach($comment in $SocialCommentDetail)  
{   
    ## Fetch the properties of the comment like Comment, Title, IsHighPriority, Url, Owner, etc.   
}
```

Comment: Do we have any powershell script to retrieve all the comments from specific publishing page ?

Comment: You can use "GetCommentsOnUrl" method for retrieving the comments from a specific publishing page by using the page URL. To get all the methods, use the URL - http://serverName:portNumber/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx.